# Which is the best optimized method for MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I have one database(MYSQL) with more than 5000 tables of same type as shown below(having 5 to 60 entries each) and using PHP for all actions. Now I think another possibility to change this database and make only one table and add all entries inside this(then there will be 1.5 million entries inside one table). The queries mostly performed is INSERT, CREATE TABLE, UPDATE, Search table and retrieve all values(in json format)  and some time DELETE.

Now if I change the database to second type having only one table then the required actions is INSERT, UPDATE, Search all relative values for specific cityname and some time DELETE entry. I am confused that which is the best optimal method for this. Please suggest me some help to optimize this database.

```
table1: id | name | nameinoanotherlang | min  | max   | model | date
        1  | abcd | gdyugdedu          | 214.2| 212.22| 3212  |2015-04-28
        .....(5 to 60 entry)

table2: id | name | nameinanotherlang | min  | max   | model | date
        1  | abcd | gdyugdedu          | 214.2| 212.22| 3212  |2015-04-28
        .....(5 to 60 entry)
table..... (more than 5000 tables)
```

another method:

only one table:

```
id | cityname | name | nameinanotherlang | min | max | model | date
......(then it will be 1.5 million entry)
```

Comment: 1 database with 5000 similar tables is definitely a terrible design. MySQL [can handle millions of records in a single table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733462/can-mysql-handle-tables-which-will-hold-about-300-million-records), but you will obviously need to make sure that everything is properly indexed or instead of your queries taking milliseconds they will take minutes.

Comment: mean in millions of entries the search query takes more time?

Comment: If you are not using indexes, any queries using that database are going to be extremely slow because MySQL will have to search through every single entry in the table. If whatever you are currently using as a criteria to separate the tables is something logical, you may want to add that as another column on the table and add an index to that column. That way when searching it will have to look through at the most 60 entries.

Comment: Also doing a [`SELECT EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) will give you a good picture of what is going on and how you can optimize your query.

Comment: do you please give me some link to know "how to add index in mysql database", here most of the queries look like, SELECT * FROM ONLYONETABLE where CITYNAME = "abcd". then how I use index here. Please help me.

Comment: Basically anything you put after the `WHERE` part of your query needs an index. If you are searching using the `cityname` column, that's the one that needs the index. If you have a unique id for every row, add one there too. Here's the [`CREATE INDEX` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).